# spikes emerged when i put displacement node in blender 3d 2.8

Tags: node-editor, shaders, displacement, bump

soo i im using image texture for base color   and  displacement
then i enabled  **experimental** from render tab 
then i enabled **displacement and bump** in materials - setting - surface - displacement.  and i observe one directional spikes which i assume should be normal to plane but arent[image: screen shot]

pls help

Comment: Should use a displacement node between disp texture and disp output. What is said on some tutorials is wrong about that. Displacement node is in vector category (this is displacement only, not vector displacement). Also this is no more an experimental feature using cycles

Comment: ok that helped, thx